# cURL call in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to perform a cURL request to grab a CSV file from the web. I've never used cURL before and so far the stuff I have seen via google doesn't seem to make sense:

the cURL call needs to look like this:

```
curl --user username:password http://somewebsite.com/events.csv
```

the code I am trying to use ( i use this to grab basic auth XML files)

```
string URL = "http://somewebsite.com/events.csv";
string Username = "username";
string Password = "password";
WebClient req = new WebClient();

CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri(URL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));

req.Credentials = myCache;

string results = null;
results = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req.DownloadData(URL));
```

This just gives me back the html for a login screen so the authentication is not happening.

Comment: Have you tried: `req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);`?

Comment: Just tried it, gave me back the same html login page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue. Apparently the request fails when you pass an `@` sign ( like in the email username ) in the username field so it must be Converted to a base 64 string. Here is the code just in case someone else runs into this:

```
    string url = "https://website.com/events.csv"; 
    WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);      
    string username = "username";
    string password = "password";
    string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
    CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
    mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
    myReq.Credentials = mycache;
    myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

    WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(content);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to use the BasicAuth protocol to login to a site?  If you're getting an HTML page back with a login screen, the site is not using BasicAuth.  BasicAuth is those old-style URLs you rarely see like:

```
username:password@http://somewebsite.com/events.csv
```

With BasicAuth, your browser handles the authentication with a little popup window.

To access this site with curl, you'll need to go through accessing the login page, filling out the form, submitting, or validating with a cookie, token, or some other method.

Comment: The XML files I use this code for are using basic auth, this call needs to use cURL to access a CSV file.

Comment: The issue is the @ sign in the username ( which is an email address) I had to convert it to Base 64.