# curl Request with C# (API ProxMox)

Tags: c#, api, curl

Can't match the C# code to the Unix command CURL is correct, responce is OK, but C# is `{"data":null}`:

```
curl -k -d "username=test@pve&password=User11" https://ip:8006/api2/json/access/ticket
```

C#

```
string url = "https://ip:8006/api2/json/access/ticket";
WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
string username = "test@pve";
string password = "User11";
string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
myReq.Credentials = mycache;
myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));
WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(content);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Response:

> {"data":null}

Comment: What status code does it return?

Comment: Hello Peter {"data":null}

Comment: What is the value of the following: `((HttpWebResponse)wr).StatusCode`?

Comment: Took from example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825846/curl-call-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, I understand but could you please extract the status code from the response object. Unless this information we can't go futher.

Comment: StatusCode = OK

Comment: please try to change the encoding from ascii to `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` [Related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13956730/13268855)

Comment: It is also strange for me why do set the `Authorization` header and the `Credentials` as well. One of them should be enough.

Comment: Did any of the suggested modifications work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, so far everything is without result, I created a proxmox event on the forum, as soon as there is a solution I will definitely publish.

Comment: Have you tried to [import the curl command](https://www.shipengine.com/docs/curl/) into postman. If it works as well then you can ask postman to [generate a C# client](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/). It will use RestSharp instead of `WebRequest` or `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Peter Csala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13268855/peter-csala), helped a lot, I used [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (senderX, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
            Run();
        }

        public static void Run() {
            var client = new RestClient("https://ip:8006/api2/json/access/ticket");

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddParameter("username", "test@pve");
            request.AddParameter("password", "password");
            
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include
            };

            dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, settings);

            var array = stuff.data;

            string ticket = array.ticket.ToString();
            string CSRFPreventionToken = array.CSRFPreventionToken.ToString();

            //Call Nodes, VM,

            var clients = new RestClient("https://ip:8006/api2/json/nodes/pve01/qemu");

            client.Timeout = 10000;
            
            var requests = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            requests.AddCookie("PVEAuthCookie", ticket);
            IRestResponse responses = clients.Execute(requests);

            var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            };

            dynamic stuffs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responses.Content, setting);

            Console.WriteLine(stuffs);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: could you please include the links what I have mentioned in the comments? Then we can delete most of the comments for your question to keep the topic clean.